# TYPO3 RealURL extension needs lower PHP version because of scheduler. Is there a workaround?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, realurl

I want to use the RealURL extension but it needs the scheduler extension which tells me the following:

> Your PHP version is higher than allowed. You can use PHP versions 7.0.0 - 7.2.99.

I am not able to change the system my TYPO3 is running on so I don't really know how to continue. Is there another extension or a workaround how I can still get the RealURL functionality?

Comment: What TYPO3 version are you using? The last LTS release supports PHP version 7.0.8 and higher but I hope you know LTS is not maintained anymore, buy an ELTS or upgrade to 9.5.x or even better 10.4.x. Btw Realurl supports PHP versions lower than 7.4

Comment: realurl needs php 5.4.0-7.3.999 (https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/blob/development/ext_emconf.php#L29), scheduler requires php 7.0 or newer (https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/scheduler/composer.json). Are you sure your system meets TYPO3 php requirements?

Comment: Write versions of PHP, TYPO3 and RealURL you are using. TBH I don't remember any Scheduler task that is added by RealURL, so I'm not sure why it's required.